# Method addToBackStack(null) is not on the property of the FragmentManager Class. Is this the proper way to go back to the previous fragment/activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

According to the tutorials that I have read, the method addToBackStack(null) is the right way to get back to the previous fragment or activity loaded. But on my part, the addToBackStack() is missing on the `ft` object that holds the FragmentManager class. Here's my code.

```
conteach.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SpecificArticleFragment spcf = new SpecificArticleFragment();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("art_id", v.getTag().toString());
                        spcf.setArguments(args);

                        FragmentManager ft = getFragmentManager();
                        ft.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, spcf).commit();
                     //I know that I should put the ft.addToBackStack(null) code here but the addToBackStack(null) method does not exist on the ft object
                    }
                 });
```

Anyway, according to my understanding if the `SpecificArticleFragment` fragment loads, I can go back to the existing fragment where the code above was located. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using Fragment manager but **addtobackStack** is a metod of **FragmentTransaction** class. see below code .

```
 // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

    Fragment fragment= new Example();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.commit();
```